# Format function for y-axis title text in highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts, yaxis

I am creating line charts with dynamic data using highcharts.js API. I need to change the title of y-axis depending upon the visible series using button. Currently I am doing this which is working fine.

```
                  $('#button1').click(function() {  
                         //alert("buton clicked");
                            series1.hide();
                            series3.show();
                            chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({
                               text: 'Volts (V)'
                           });

                        $('#button0').removeAttr('disabled');
                    });
```

Now when I download the chart ,It always shows the first y axis title I have set in the chart options, not the one i explicitly change upon click function. Is there any formtter function I can use to set title text of y-axis in charts options. I have tried doing the following

```
      yAxis: {            
        labels: {
        text:{
            formatter: function () {
            if(this.series=="Series 1")
                return 'Power kW';
             else 
             return 'Voltage kW';
            }            
        }
        }
    }
```

But It is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `axis.update()` instead of changing svg attribute directly.

```
$('#button1').click(function() {  
                     //alert("buton clicked");
                        series1.hide();
                        series3.show();
                        chart.yAxis[0].update({
                          title: {
                            text: 'Volts'
                          }
                        });

                    $('#button0').removeAttr('disabled');
                });
```

See [API DOCS - axis.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.update).

Comment: Thank u so much. It worked.I was updating the series but didn't think of doing this.